# Using lower() in a trigger after declaring a variable

Tags: mysql

I want to `set` some variable i have declared in mysql to lowercase in a trigger using this code

```
declare last_inserted_number VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '0800100200';
declare last_inserted_message VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'Lorem Ipsum';

set last_inserted_number = NEW.dest_msisdn;
set last_inserted_message = LOWER(NEW.text_message);
```

`set last_inserted_message = LOWER(NEW.text_message);` do not throw an error although i suspect  i may have used `lower()` in the wrong way when i wrote `LOWER(NEW.text_message)`

Should i be using `lower()` in this way?.

Comment: Is this causing you some sort of problem? What is going wrong?

Comment: There is no problem at all.Program runs fine.No errors at all.

Comment: Then what are you asking, and why?

Comment: My program is really big i can't paste it all here.You have a way with words i will give you that. My first line looks like this where i am using the variable `if (not exists(select id from transactions where tel = last_inserted_number) && last_inserted_message = 'loan') then`

Comment: Why would you post your entire real program? Or even consider that?

Comment: Once i finish what i am doing currently,i shall write my own database engine and programming language and helpful people like you shall be so screwed because there shall be no more f***ness left to spread. Just happy people doing their tasks. By the way i cannot stand mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `LOWER()` in your question should work without flaws.

The only circumstance where `LOWER()` doesn't work is on a binary (varbinary, blob) input.